# Stata access element of matrix as scalar or macro

Tags: stata

I'm generating a column of random numbers in Stata, trying out different seeds to see which one gives the best results. I created 250 random numbers and pasted them into the code of the foreach loop seen below. The ellipsis represents ~240 seeds .

```
save "`datadir'ProviderCounty", replace

foreach x in 89583 31214 65326 61107 54662 91414 86171 14809 19625 . . . 74397 85273 {

    use "`datadir'ProviderCounty", replace
    display `x'
    set seed `x'
    generate rannum = uniform()
    . . . 
}
```

I'd like to replace that long line of 250 numbers by reading them from Excel into a matrix like this and then iterating through the matrix one by one.

```
* Import seeds randomly generated in Excel
clear
import excel "`datadirIN'Random Number Seeds.xlsx", sheet("Sheet1") cellrange(A2:A252) firstrow
mkmat Seeds, matrix(matSeeds)
scalar mlen = rowsof(matSeeds)
clear
```

This would go between the line starting with "save . . ." and the foreach line. What I don't know how to do is iterate through the matrix. I need a line that replaces the foreach line with a line(s) that the iterates through matrix and places the seed number in the macro "x".

Answer (score 6):

I hope I am misunderstanding, but the underlying idea appears fallacious. The sole merit of using a specified seed is to ensure reproducibility of detailed results, in the sense that other people using the same program and the same data are at least assured of the same results (and hence have means of checking exactly what you did). Otherwise if results depend sensitively on a particular seed, then either the sample size is too small, or the problem is too fragile for any results to be credible. How are you going to report this? If you suppress the fact that you had to search for suitable results, then that would widely be regarded as unacceptable. If you publicise the fact, you publicise results that are stamped as between dubious and useless. I would advise discussing your idea with supervisors, mentors or colleagues as appropriate. If they're suggesting this, explaining why you think it is a good idea would be needed wherever you present the results.

All that said, Stata matrices have rows and columns so that given a column vector, its elements are generically *matname*`[`*i*`, 1]`. Subscripting is defined in any documentation on Stata matrices e.g. http://www.stata.com/help.cgi?matrix

So the loop you seem to be implying might be

```
mkmat Seeds, matrix(matSeeds)

forval i = 1/`= rowsof(matSeeds)' {
    ...
    set seed `= matSeeds[`i', 1]'  
    ... 
}
```

http://www.stata.com/help.cgi?macro documents evaluations on the fly of (in this case) scalars and matrix elements.

EDIT: The syntax used here is documented at `help macro` or at http://www.stata.com/manuals14/pmacro.pdf. Here is an example:

```
. mat foo  = J(1, 1, 42)

. set seed `=foo[1,1]'

. display c(seed)
X51535c3ec43f462544a474abacbdd93d386b

. mat foo  = J(1, 1, 666)

. set seed `=foo[1,1]'

. display c(seed)
X97b5c5aec43f462544a474abacbdd93d2d9c
```

The underlying problem here is that `set seed` will not itself evaluate expressions fed to it. There are various work-arounds including defining a local macro and then typing a macro reference. The way that Stata works is that the macro is evaluated before `set` sees its arguments. The syntax shown here cuts out the macro by an evaluation on the fly.

The case used here is that where the *expansion_optr* is an equals sign `=` followed by *exp*, namely an expression to be evaluated. In this case, the expression is just a matrix element.

Comment: Thanks for being judgmental and wrong. http://www.stata.com/help.cgi?matrix doesn't show A left quote before the equal sign? Seems mighty odd.

Comment: You could explain why you think my comments are wrong or irrelevant.  It's unwelcome to you to hear, but "trying out different seeds to see which one gives the best results" is, unqualified, a canonical misunderstanding of the point of simulation based on random number generation. Otherwise my comments stand unrebutted.

Comment: What is puzzling you about the syntax? It is syntax for `set` and nothing to do with `matrix` itself. Did you try it? Did you try the syntax you are guessing instead? Again, refutation of incorrect ideas is welcome.

Comment: Thanks for being judgmental and wrong. I'm trying to choose a sample that is most representative of the population based on Chi-square of several categorical variables. You can apologize now. Neither of your links show extraction of a matrix element into a local or scalar. A left quote before the equal sign? I bet that's wrong, too.

Comment: I'll confine myself to technical remarks.  You are incorrect. I'll edit the answer to show why.

Comment: For those interested, a series of papers starting with William H. Kruskal and Frederick Mosteller. 1979. Representative sampling, I: Non-scientific literature. _International Statistical Review_  47: 13–24 examines an  elusive and problematic idea in detail.

Comment: My first paragraph was, and is, a good-faith attempt to warn the OP (and any others interested) that as explained the underlying statistical idea appeared dubious. I stand by it as fair comment. Arguably, the statistical merits of an idea are off-topic here but as a statistical person too I think it's appropriate and ethical to flag possibly problematic cases. The OP evidently regards the approach as thoroughly defensible. I remain very puzzled, but I say no more.  As usual, readers can and should judge for themselves.

Comment: There is no justification in the literature for your proposal, which is not simple random sampling. There are accepted designs to make sample characteristics match the population well. Some are: stratified sampling, systematic sampling, balanced sampling, lattice sampling, two-stage sampling, with stratification in the second stage, sampling with probability proportional to size.  Yves Tillé 's book  Sampling algorithms, Springer, 2006 covers balanced sampling, implemented in his R sampling package.

Comment: Lattice sampling is covered in Raymond Jessen, 1978, Statistical Survey Techniques, Wiley.

Post-sampling adjustments can also be applied to achieve closer resemblance of sampling and population on multiple characteristics.  Raking and calibration are two well-established methods. See Sarndal, C.E. 2007. The calibration approach in survey theory and practice. Survey Methodology 33, no. 2: 99-119.
http://www.statcan.gc.ca/pub/12-001-x/2007002/article/10488-eng.pdf.

Comment: Some clarification:
1) raking can make estimated sample frequencies *exactly* match population frequencies for multiple variables